# Execute javascript in a file called through post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I have a php file(*index.php*) that contains a button, wherein if that button is clicked, it will trigger a javascript function that will post request on a php file(*login.php*). Now on that login.php if a condition is true, I will be redirected to a url, using javascript. For this example, I will not ask how to redirect but just to perform a simple `alert()` on that login.php;

I found an answer saying I should so this:

```
<?php // some php code
   // php condition is true {
   echo "<script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Alert worked.');
         </script>";
   // }
   // more php code 
?>
```

It performs the `echo` but never executes the script.
**How could I execute javascript in a file(that is called through post request).**

Comment: Is this because the file is in server side, and not actually present in browser?

Comment: This is a bad construction.  Instead, have the AJAX call return a value (true or false), and have the original javasrcipt execute the redirect based on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this works using AJAX you should add this response to DOM page. For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('/test.php', function (script) { 
        $('body').append(script);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Include the jQuery JS library in your page to use this solution

Comment: This doesn't execute the javascript from the `login.php`, but it does the job, it executes the script printed/echoed in the `login.php`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drop out of PHP and let the JS actually run. With the echo you are just writing it to the page that is being produced.

```
<?php // some php code
   // php condition is true
 {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Alert worked.');
</script>";
<?php
}
// more php code 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As **cale_b** and **Andrew Koper** mentioned, you need to rethink your approach. If login.php is being used solely to route the user without displaying any output then you will never see your Javascript alert.

You can make a post via AJAX to login.php and return a value:

**AJAX POST**: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'login.php',
    data: data_to_post,
    success: function(e) {
        // e will be whatever you've returned from your login.php script

        // Perform conditional check on e 
        (if (e === 'success') {
            // Alert message here
            alert("You've been logged in!");

            // Redirect user here as needed
            window.location = 'www.your_url.com';
        }
    }
    dataType: dataType
});
```

I should mention that this solution is dependent on JQuery being included:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

JQuery - Getting Started: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the structure of what you're trying to do - based on what you wrote - doesn't sound right.  It sounds like you want to:

1. Attach a click event handler to the button on your index page
2. On click, send an AJAX request to the server. (If you have a form with some variables that need to be submitted/stored on the server, used POST.  If you need to get a true/false variable from the server, use GET.  It doesn't make sense to have a page on the server with a true/false variable on it that isn't served up.  It doesn't make sense to have page with a true/false variable on it that is served up for a microsecond just to get the variable to serve up another page.)
3. "window.location = 'http://whatever.com'" will show the user a new web page via JavaScript.  Or the button could send an HTTP request to a PHP file on the server and the PHP could send back a web page based on a true/false test, like normal.